# PHP separate string

Tags: php, string, split, yii2

I have a string that contains `128.82`. I want to split/separate them in `100` and `28.82`.

```
var_dump(substr($kwh,0,3));
        die();
```

It gives me `128`.

How can I separate the `100` and `28.82`?

Any help would be highly appreciated

**Note:** I am setting this because I have defined slabs. `1-100`, `101-150`, and so on. So I need to set them according to the slabs. The slabs may differ as it could be `1-50`, `51-100`, `100-150`, and so on. so I have to divide/split `128.82` like `50` for `1-50`, `50` for `51-100` and then `28.82` for `101-150`

Comment: substr is a string function, what you are looking for seems like a simple subtraction, no?

Comment: Not sure what is your goal here? Are you looking for a algorithm that will do that thing for various numbers or looking for a solution for only this specific 128.82? Because this is basic math...

Comment: You can not do this by “splitting” alone, because the `100` does not exist as part of your input _string_. This obviously involves a bit of a “math component” as well. But for us to be able to give a proper answer, you should give more than one single example, resp. specify the conditions/restrictions that apply here a bit better.

Comment: Put the upper boundaries of your slabs into an array - `[50, 100, 150, …`]. Then just loop over that, and substract the current slab value (resp., the difference between the current and the previous slab) from your input value. If the result gets below zero, you know that it’s time to stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '128.82'; // we’re doing math here, so actually we’ll be working with numbers,
                   // but PHP will automatically cast here
$slabs = [50, 100, 150, 200];

$result = [];
$previous_slab = 0;

foreach($slabs as $slab) {
  // calculate distance between current and previous slab
  $slab_distance = $slab - $previous_slab;
  // if current remainder of input value is >= distance, add distance to result,
  // and subtract distance from remainder of input
  if( $input >= $slab_distance ) {
    $result[] = $slab_distance;
    $input -= $slab_distance;
  }
  // otherwise, add remainder as last item of result, and break out of the loop here
  else {
    $result[] = $input;
    break;
  }
  $previous_slab = $slab;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Result for the given slabs:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 50
  1 => int 50
  2 => float 28.82
```

Result for [50, 75, 150, 200]:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 50
  1 => int 25
  2 => float 53.82
```

Comment: I have 3 points `slab_start`, `slab_end`, and `rate` as I have mentioned in another question. How can I manage them in it ?

Comment: You don’t need the slab start values here, my array above is only the slab ends. (All that under the assumption, that your slaps start at 1, and are continuous and in proper order.) And where/how the rate is supposed to come into this, does not become clear in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63070569/1427878 either so far.

Comment: Each slab has a rate.

Comment: And each bunny rabbit usually has two ears. And? So what? What is supposed to _happen_ with that rate? How does it factor in to the calculation?

Comment: rate is used to calculate the bill against the unit(s).

Comment: Please stop giving these one-sentence-or-less replies all the time. Give a _proper_ explanation of what you want to calculate, and how. Don’t expect us to figure that out by looking at your code, explain it properly, using your WORDs. (And in this case, I think it would indeed be preferable, if you did that in the/a new question now, instead of here in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split `128.82` into `100` and `28.82`
You can do it like this:

```
<?php
function calcSlabSize($size) {
    $slab = floor($size / 50)*50;
    return [$slab,$size-$slab];
}

print_r( calcSlabSize(128.82));
```

This will result in:

```
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 28.82 )
```