# Slab wise electricity bill calculation in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, billing

I am working on `yii2`. I want to calculate electricity bill slab wise. For this, I have already inserted slabs and their respective rates in a table. Now I want to calculate it.

My units are `128.82` and below is my slab and their rates.

[image]

I am able to carry out the slabs by using the following query

```
$mData = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT s.`slab_start`, s.`slab_end`, s.`rate`, r.`cust_id` 
FROM `mdc_tariff_slabs` s 
INNER JOIN `mdc_meter_cust_rel` r ON s.`t_id` = r.`tariff_id`
WHERE r.`cust_id` = $consumer_no")->queryAll();

array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(1) "1" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "100" ["rate"]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "101" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "150" ["rate"]=> string(2) "12" } [2]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "151" ["slab_end"]=> NULL ["rate"]=> string(2) "14" } }
```

**Note:** The slabs may differ in future

I have tried the following code, set the slabs according to my requirements and tried to get the bill

```
 public static function calcBill($units)
{

    if($units < 100){
        $bill = $units*10;
    }elseif($units > 100 && $units <=150){
        $temp = 100*10;
        $remaining_units = $units - 100;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *12);
    }else{
        $temp = (100*10)+ (100*12);
        $remaining_units = $units - 150;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *14);
    }

    echo $bill;
    die();
}
```

The bill is `1345.84`.

Now what I am trying to do is to pass the slabs as well and not to hard code them. I am finding it a bit difficult.

**Update 1**

I have 3 slabs/units limit. Each slab has its own rate. Rate is used to calculate the bill. Below is the scenario.

- if units are <= 100 then charge Rs 10 rupee/unit
- if units are > 100 && <= 150 then charge Rs 12 rupee/unit
- if units are > 150 then charge Rs 14 rupee/unit

In my array, I have all the three values except for the last one which has only `slab_start` and `rate`.

By hard coding the slabs and rate I can calculate the bill but I want to calculate while using the array.

So the code may be look likes

```
if($units < slab_end){
        $bill = $units*rate;
    }elseif($units > slab_start && $units <=slab_end){<=slab_end
        $temp = prev_slab_start *rate; 
        $remaining_units = $units - prev_slab;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *rate);
    }else{
        $temp = (prev_slab*10)+ (prev_slab*12);
        $remaining_units = $units - slab_start;
        $bill = $temp + ($remaining_units *14);
    }
```

I don't know the above logic is correct or not.

**Note:** Slab range and quantity may be changed. So I want to have a generic function that will do the needful

**Update 2**

Following the solution mentioned.

```
 $array = ArrayHelper::map($mData, 'slab_end', 'rate');

var_dump($array);
die();
```

The above gives me

```
array(3) { [100]=> string(2) "10" [150]=> string(2) "12" [""]=> string(2) "14" }
```

Then I have added a function

```
 public function billCalc($input, $slabs)
{
    $result = [];
    $bill = 0;
    $previous_slab = 0;

    foreach($slabs as $slab => $rate)
    {

        // calculate distance between current and previous slab
        $slab_distance = $slab - $previous_slab;
        // if current remainder of input value is >= distance, add distance to result,
        // and subtract distance from remainder of input
        if( $input >= $slab_distance )
        {
            $result[] = $slab_distance;
            $bill += $slab_distance * $rate;
            $input -= $slab_distance;
        }// otherwise, add remainder as last item of result, and break out of the loop here
        else
            {
            $result[] = $input;
            $bill += $input * $rate;
            break;
        }
        $previous_slab = $slab;
    }
    var_dump($result, $bill);
    exit();
}
```

Now I am facing an issue. When the input is less than `150` the result is perfectly ok, but when it's greater or equal to `150` I am getting below error

> A non-numeric value encountered

It's giving me this error at

`$slab_distance = $slab - $previous_slab;`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As if I did not just give you a solution for that under your previous question, which you asked not even an hour ago …? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069762/php-separate-string

Comment: Apparently with the rates, this is supposed to be different here, or at least a more complex calculation/formula, according to the discussion below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070039/1427878 But this still lacks a _proper_ explanation of how your rates are supposed to figure into the calculation, IMHO. Explain that using your _words_, please, instead of going, “here is code, you figure it out”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you simply want to multiply the amount covered by each slab (“units”) with the rate then - so I would create an array that has the slab end as *key*, and the rate as value - then you can simply loop over that with the extended foreach syntax, and have access to the rate corresponding to the slab at all times.

Expanding on [my answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070039/1427878), this would look like this then:

```
$input = '128.82';
$slabs = [100 => 10, 150 => 12, PHP_INT_MAX => 14];

$result = [];
$bill = 0;
$previous_slab = 0;

foreach($slabs as $slab => $rate) {
  // calculate distance between current and previous slab
  $slab_distance = $slab - $previous_slab;
  // if current remainder of input value is >= distance, add distance to result,
  // and subtract distance from remainder of input
  if( $input >= $slab_distance ) {
    $result[] = $slab_distance;
    $bill += $slab_distance * $rate;
    $input -= $slab_distance;
  }
  // otherwise, add remainder as last item of result, and break out of the loop here
  else {
    $result[] = $input;
    $bill += $input * $rate;
    break;
  }
  $previous_slab = $slab;
}

var_dump($result, $bill);
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => int 100
  1 => float 28.82

float 1345.84
```

My approach again uses only the upper slab boundaries here - you don’t have one in your last record from the database, so I am substituting PHP_INT_MAX here for that NULL value. Taking that into account, when you create that array from your database content, should be not challenge, I hope.

(If you only need the `1345.84` as result here, and not the array that shows the distribution accross the indivudual slabs, then you can just remove all lines that contain `$result` anywhere.)

Comment: how can I convert `array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(1) "1" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "100" ["rate"]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "101" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "150" ["rate"]=> string(2) "12" } [2]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "151" ["slab_end"]=> NULL ["rate"]=> string(2) "14" } }
` to `[100 => 10, 150 => 12, PHP_INT_MAX => 14];`

Comment: Also, how will it work `N` number of slabs and rates? To mention the last slab will only have `slab_start` and `rate`

Comment: I am facing an issue. Kindly check my `update 2`

Comment: An empty string, and `PHP_INT_MAX`, are not the same thing. We want to be able to use those key values for mathematical operations here, so you can not just use `''` as the key here.

Comment: How can I then put `PHP_INT_MAX` in my array ?

Comment: You asked about that already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078251/yii2-associative-array - why did you accept the answer there, when it does not even do what you want? Plus, figuring out this minor part of the whole thing, don’t you think that is something you should be able to handle yourself, maybe?

Comment: Even with hardcoding the `NULL` part with `PHP_INT_MAX` or some other flag. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Well then you probably “hardcoded” it wrong … what response do you expect, when you only give this little _useful_ information?

Comment: I have hardcoded it in my table. then I tried to fetch the data and map them accordingly which gives me `array(3) { [100]=> string(2) "10" [150]=> string(2) "12" ["PHP_INT_MAX"]=> string(2) "14" }`

Comment: `"PHP_INT_MAX"` and `PHP_INT_MAX` are two different things. You need to either _replace_ the NULL value with the _actual_ value of `PHP_INT_MAX` - or you could just set a high enough integer value instead of NULL in your database table to begin with.

Comment: Ok let me have a try. Thanks for the help