# Yii2 associative array

Tags: php, arrays, yii2-advanced-app

I have a query from which I am getting an array.

```
$mData = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT s.slab_start, s.slab_end, s.rate, r.cust_id 
 FROM mdc_tariff_slabs s 
 INNER JOIN mdc_meter_cust_rel r ON s.t_id = r.tariff_id
 WHERE r.cust_id = $consumer_no")->queryAll();
```

By `var_dump($mData)` I am getting

`array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(1) "1" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "100" ["rate"]=>  string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "101" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "150"  ["rate"]=> string(2) "12" } [2]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "151" ["slab_end"]=> NULL  ["rate"]=> string(2) "14" } }`

In actual I want the above array into like below

```
[100 => 10, 150 => 12, PHP_INT_MAX => 14];
```

Above `100` is the first `slab_end` and `10` is the rate of that value. `150` is the second `slab_end` and along with it's `rate`. The last slab_end will always be empty/NULL so in that case, I am putting `PHP_INT_MAX`. There will be `N` number of slab_end and rates.

**Update 1 MDC Table Model**

```
class MdcTariffSlabs extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'mdc_tariff_slabs';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['slab_name', 'slab_start', 'rate'], 'required'],
        [['slab_start', 'slab_end', 't_id'], 'integer'],
        [['slab_name', 'rate'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['t_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => MdcTariff::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['t_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}

 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'Primary Key',
        'slab_name' => 'Slab Name',
        'slab_start' => 'Start',
        'slab_end' => 'End',
        'rate' => 'Rate',
        't_id' => 'Tariff ID',
    ];
}

/**
 * Gets query for [[T]].
 *
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getT()
{
    return $this->hasOne(MdcTariff::className(), ['id' => 't_id']);
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `ActiveRecord` to get values and after that `ArrayHelper::map()` to create necessary array.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco can you please give me an example?

Comment: Do you have `mdc_tariff_slabs` table model? Can you post it?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I have posted it please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$data = MdcTariffSlabs::find()
   ->joinWith(['t'])
   ->where('T_TABLE_NAME.cust_id' => $consumer_no)
   ->all();
```

//Then map your data

```
$array = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'slab_end', 'rate');
```

Documentation: [Building Maps](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array#building-maps)

//Output should be like this

```
[100 => 10, 150 => 12, ...];
```

Comment: I am getting this `array(3) { [100]=> string(2) "10" [150]=> string(2) "12" [""]=> string(2) "14" }` 

with the last one empty, I am getting some issues. That's why I need to put some tag into it while mapping.